# eclipse keybindings settings

Tags: eclipse, settings

Where does eclipse keep it's key-binding settings? I want to transfer them from one system to another. If there is a tool for this that would be good but if not, I'm willing to copy files (really all settings should be the same on both systems.)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

export all your Eclipse prefs to a file.

```
File->Export->General->Preferences
```

Import has an option to import only key settings from this file.

```
File->Import->General->Preferences
```

Comment: Note that you can only see keybindings in the Export list once you have configured some non-default keybindings!

Comment: At least in Eclipse Juno you have to restart Eclipse for the imported keys to be visible in `Preferences` (and usable)!

Comment: I think there's is a bug in Juno (20120614-1722) which lets the import/export ignore unbound keys. In the preferences window, I don't see the default binding anymore but the actually pressing the keys still provokes the default behavior.

Comment: thanks rasha its true you have to restart ... was wondering why the shortcuts were not visible.

Comment: @Wolfgang yes there is a bug that prevents importing key settings properly. If you want to change the default key, you only can get things to work if you restore, unbind and set the key setting again. This renders the whole feature useless. Build id: 20121004-1855

Comment: There is a bug in Juno that messes up export/import of key settings. Workaround: save and restore the key binding entries from `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.‌​workbench.prefs` and this complete file `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`.

Answer (score 17):

Export: File -> Export -> General -> Preferences -> Keys Preferences

Import: File -> Import -> General -> Preferences -> Choose file

Comment: This saves them as CSV (to be put into Excel, I guess), and there's no way to import keys from CSV, AFAIK

Comment: As of Eclipse 3.4, this method exports the keys as Eclipse preferences

Comment: Yes, but there's no way to import them, which kinda defeats the purpose. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong :)  The "prefs" file format allows you to selectively import the "Keys Preferences" or whatever else you exported.

Comment: @Kevin, but only if you exported as prefs. Under the General->Keys is an export CSV button for the keys only, which implies that you can export and import them. But there is no import functionality for that file.