# How to exchange ONLY the keybindings between eclipse instances

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, preferences, transfer

When I exchange the complete preferences, my customized key bindings are exported along with the other stuff, but if i select **Keys Preferences** from the **Export**->**Preferences** menu, only a useless small subset of the shortcuts is exported.
 
There is a possibility to export all the bindings from the **Keys** Page which is worse then useless as it suggests a feature thet isn't there.
I don't want to mess up the complete setup, so: 
 is there a way to transfer just the key bindings and nothing else?

Thank you

btw : [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481073/eclipse-keybindings-settings) deals with the same topic but isnt helpful for the reasons above.

Comment: If the feature isn't there, then open a bug in the Eclipse Bugzilla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no automatic way as far as I know but the resulting file is XML, so you can export all the preferences and delete everything you don't want.

The result should still load into Eclipse.

Comment: Makes me ashamed for my IDE to have to do that...sigh

Comment: Well, you can always write a plugin or a small ANT script which cleans the file for you. The problem is that there are so many ways in which you could want to export your prefs (like "only the JRE settings"), it's probably impossible to create a UI to handle them all.

Comment: I guess i'll script it, no problem. Its just that eclipse has 2 ways to suggest that exactly the thing i want is possible and than just lets you drop in the mud halfway. Thank you for the swift reply Aaron