# How do I import and export keyboard bindings in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [eclipse keybindings settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481073/eclipse-keybindings-settings)

How do I import and export keyboard bindings in Eclipse?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

File->Export...->General->Preferences, then choose to "Export all" your preferences or just the "Keys Preferences"; make sure to point out the file where you want your preferences to be saved, and finally click "Finish".

File->Import...->General->Preferences, then point the preference file you created when exporting your preferences; choose to "Import all" or specific preferences, and finally click on "Finish".