# Export all key bindings in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, settings

I'm trying to export *all* key bindings from Eclipse.

I've tried File > Export... | General > Preference | Keys Preferences as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528031/how-do-i-import-and-export-keyboard-bindings-in-eclipse) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481073/eclipse-keybindings-settings). This will, however, export only the bindings that are changed in regards to default binding scheme.

I want to export all bindings, even if default shortcut is kept. Additionally, it would be great if commands that have no shortcut assigned are also exported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an 'Export CSV' button on the Keys preference page - 'Preferences > General > Keys'.

This exports all the commands with a key binding as a CSV format text file.