# Why Does Eclipse (Juno) Ignore Key Bindings for "Ctrl+Shift+Arrow"?

Tags: eclipse, macos, key-bindings, eclipse-juno

In Eclipse on OS X, I find the default behaviour of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd> key combinations extremely annoying. To make those combinations behave like every other editor on OS X, I changed them, along with many others.

Now I'm attempting to update Eclipse from Indigo (3.8) to Juno (4.2). I did this simply by downloading and extracting a new clean copy of Juno with none of my old Indigo plugins. After installing, every one of my workspace's custom key bindings works in Juno *except* the aforementioned combinations.

In Juno (and the current Kepler build), no matter what command I bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>, Eclipse ignores it and always executes the default command, which is some sort of "Select Enclosing Element" command that's very similar to the default binding of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>↑</kbd>.

If I go back and open the same workspace in Indigo, the bindings work fine again. This implies a bug in Juno, but I have't turned anything up in my searches yet. Has anyone else noticed this behavior? Better yet, has anyone found a workaround?

### Edit

Since I can't find any record of this issue, I've [filed a bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402065).

Answer (score 1):

I have experimented a lot of issues using Eclipse Juno in OS X as well as in Windows and Ubuntu, I think there are a lot of bugs that need to be reported. One of them is the one you mention, I had to go back to Indigo to work without that annoying issue again. You can notice as well that Eclipse Juno is slower, for OS X users is not perceptible but in other o.s like Windows, you can feel the delays, Juno consumes more resources, I know it has a "improved" ui but if it consumes more performance for me there's no point. I haven't found a workaround but I can tell you that I experimented the same behavior and had to get back to Indigo and now I'm working without problems. Best regards.

Comment: "I think there are a lot of bugs that need to be reported."

So, report them!  And either install the patches from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation or go to SR2 when it's available.

Comment: some of them I've already reported, I want to confirm some others, since it is not the same behavior for all the O.S

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar to you. Might be happening due to a bug in Juno's importing of key bindings.

See this related thread: [eclipse keybindings settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481073/eclipse-keybindings-settings)

The workaround on that thread from sulai that worked for me was to manually copy the files

> workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.‌​‌​workbench.prefs

and

> workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi

to my new workspace, rather than relying on Eclipse's import (whether implicitly or explicitly done).